# scalable sites

Tags: scalability, cluster-computing

facebook, skype, myspace etc... all have millions and millions of users, does anyone know what their architecture looks like.  Is it distributed on different nodes or do they use massive clusters?

Comment: I am sure this was already asked but couldnt find it.

Answer (score 5):

Check below link to read how bigger applications like Amason, eBay, Flickr, Google etc. lives with high traffic.

http://highscalability.com/links/weblink/24

Interesting website for architects.

(I blogged about this earlier after a research for a BIG project - http://blog.ninethsense.com/high-scalability-how-big-applications-works/)

Answer (score 2):

[Memcached](http://www.danga.com/memcached/) is used by a lot of sites with a lot of users, including [Facebook](http://www.facebook.com/note.php?note_id=39391378919). You can find lots of blogs that discuss the architecture of various high traffic Web sites. A long time ago I listened to [this Arcast](http://channel9.msdn.com/shows/ARCast.TV/ARCastTV-PlentyOfFishcom-How-one-man-beat-the-big-guys/) which I thought was quite interesting (if you do ASP.NET with SQL Server)

Answer (score 1):

Facebook uses [Hadoop/Hive](http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/Hive) and [Erlang](http://erlang.org/) among other things (see http://www.facebook.com/notes.php?id=9445547199)

Answer (score 0):

Hey this may not directly answer your question.
Interesting to watch nonetheless. See
[facebook software stack](http://www.infoq.com/presentations/Facebook-Software-Stack).